# Make Ubuntu use AMDGPU instead of LLVMPIPE or AMDGPU-PRO

Tags: 16.04, drivers, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I borked an installation of AMDGPU-Pro, and was able to recover and uninstall it. It would boot to a blinking cursor that never changed, and attempts to switch to other TTYs would result a flickering screen as Linux seemed to jump between the original and the new TTY over and over. Eventually, I was forced to use recovery to uninstall AMDGPU-Pro.

When I did, my system went to LLVMpipe instead of returning to the open-source AMDGPU driver. I can't seem to get it to go back to AMDGPU - purging and reinstalling xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu had no effect.

I had AMDGPU working before on my card (RX 460), so I'm quite sure it's supported. I just can't seem to find how to blacklist radeon or LLVMpipe and force the use of AMDGPU.

Comment: Does `apt-get -f install` help? Are `libdrm-amdgpu1` and `linux-image-extra` (dpkg -l | grep linux-image-extra) packages installed?

Comment: The install command does nothing; and libdrm-amdgpu1 is already installed Searching for linux-image-extra lists a number of packages for different kernel versions. I'm currently on 4.4.0-104 I think.

Comment: Can you install the amdgpu-pro drivers again, and then immediately run the uninstall script, without rebooting? I'm not sure what you might have accidentally caused to break at this point during the purge from a live boot. You might want to run `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` too, and hopefully that will remove some of the older kernels.

Comment: Done. No change, unfortunately. I seem to have really screwed this install up.

Comment: Ever sorted this out? I just managed for mess up my configuration in exactly the same way. Also have an RX460.

Answer (score -1):

I am new to Linux but this fixed it and had the same problem with my rx560 boots up to flickering mouse cursor and fixed it by instaling amdgpu install instead amdgpu-pro install in amdgpu-pro driver folder.
Hope it helps if that is what u need.